# I'm getting a Key Error Message after using a For loop and then trying to access the columns by name in a Python Series

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, time-series, keyerror

I hope that someone can help me here. I'm pretty new to Python and I got stuck with a For Loop to create a couple of time shifts for my datetime Series. Once I iterated over the shifts and want access the columns by name to calculate the percentage change, I get a Key Error.

Here is what my code looks like:

```
i=1
x=50
for i in range (x):
    df_data_1['visits_lag_',i] = df_data_1['visits'].shift(i)
```

The output looks the following:
[df.dtypes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7AxE2.png)

Now, If I want to calculate or access one of the newly created columns, I receive a Key Error Message:

```
 df_data_1['percent_change_test'] = 
(df_data_1['visits']/df_data_1['(visits_lag_, 1)'])*100
```

It says:

[image: Key Error]

Please, can anyone help me here, what I'm doing all wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is related to how you call the newly created column.
Instead of:

```
df_data_1["(visits_lag_, 1)"]
```

Try to do:

```
df_data_1[("visits_lag_", 1)]
```

Comment: You are welcome! Could you please accept my answer? thanks!